# Atom editor - emmet set language

Tags: atom-editor, emmet

I just started using Atom editor after switching from Sublime Text 3. I'm having a couple of issues though and one of them is that I have emmet installed but the files I'm using have sytax highlighting set for ExpressionEngine or Craft-Twig not html and this is stopping the emmet shortcuts from working.

Is there a way to set emmet to expand html with syntax highlighting other than html.

so for example:

section>ul.list-inline>(li>a>lorem2)*3 and hit tab expands to:

```
<section>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Quasi, nihil.</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nam, nobis.</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

This works if I set the file to html, but I want it to work when set to expressionengine or craft-twig. I had it working like this when using Sublime Text.

Comment: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom#tab-key

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok I looked there but am having trouble following the instructions to "open DevTools and find corresponding <atom-text-editor>" can't find where to open DevTools and google is failing me.

Comment: View > Developer > Toggle Developer Tools

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use extend the snippets, as it's currently done for JSX. The following is taken from [`snippets.json`](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json#L985-L989):

```
"jsx": {
    "filters": "jsx, html",
    "extends": "html",
    "profile": "xml"
}
```

Check the [snippets documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) for details.